# BLE - connection multi and writeCharacteristic multiple

Tags: android, connection, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have to connect at least two devices to one Android device. But I don't know how to connect multiple connections and multiple command send. plz help me... i really don't know that....

I just can connect one BLE device to One Android device.

first, i connected two devices(same UUID, different address) in one Service like example

```
BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice("aa:12:12:33");
mGatt = device.connectGatt(mContext, false, mGattCallback);

BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice("bb:18:66:44");
mGatt = device.connectGatt(mContext, false, mGattCallback);
```

i can listen to each device action(they have a button), GattCallback's callback comes from two devices action, but i can't send BluetoothGatt.writeCahracteristic to two devices.

Comment: I really researched almost two weeks, but i don't know..

Comment: What is your issue? You simply execute the connectGatt method on multiple BluetoothDevice objects.

Comment: @Emil rewrite my article. I can't send writeCahracteristic to two devices at once...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, but i solved this problem. Before i tried to use one Service(Android Component) but i used Service each BLE Device. but i think this is not solution, because if i have to more BLE device, I should to prepare maximum Service Component.

Comment: You should use different BluetoothGattCallback objects for each connection. Then you should of course also store the BluetoothGatt object returned from each connectGatt in different variables.

Comment: @Emil Yes Thanks, in my case each BluetoothService has each BluetoothGattCallback objects. Thank you for your advice